# Excel Command Button

Tags: excel, button, save

I am looking to program a button in excel where when clicked it will save the file to a specific drive path and a file name.  the file name will equal the value of a designated cell.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far and any issues encountered. The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You could write a macro that references the cell as the name, and hardcode the rest of the file name. If you simply record macro where you save as and save a the excel sheet to your desired path, you should get most of the code written by Excel already, but it will probably look similar to this:

```
Set WS = ActiveSheet
Set MyCellContent = WS.Range("a1")

MyFileName = Range("A1")
WS.Copy
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
ChDir MyPath

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
MyFileName, _
ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
CreateBackup:=False
```

This assumes the file name is in cell A1. MyPath will be replaced by the path to where you want the document saved.
You will have to change the code of the macro to reference the A1 cell (or whatever cell the file's name will be placed in)
You can then just add a button on your sheet and assign the newly recorded macro to the button.

Answer (score 0):

Assign this macro to your button:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim pathh As String
    Dim filespec As String
    pathh = "C:\TestFolder\"
    filespec = pathh & Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B9").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=filespec, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
End Sub
```

modify the:

1. path
2. sheet name
3. cell address

to suit your needs.